# How search in a website using Jsoup in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to use https://www.devicespecifications.com/ website in my application. There is a search frame in this website which user enters a phone model, then presses the enter key and navigates to another page which shows all specifications of that phone. I want to do this programmatically in kotlin using Jsoup library.
The page source related to search frame is: `<input id="search" type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Search" disabled />`
My code in kotlin is:
`val doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.devicespecifications.com").get() val searchText=doc.getElementById("search") searchText?.attr("value", phoneName)`
I can set a value in serach frame, but I don't know how submit it programmatically and navigate to specification page. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I don't think JSoup allows you to interact with a website, it only does HTML parsing AFAIK. You'll need a tool like Selenium.

Comment: I think it is possible. I have already logged in to a website using Jsoup and now I just want to search on a website, which is an easier task.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a request to this url:

https://www.devicespecifications.com/index.php?action=search&language=en&search=nokia

It will give you back the preview HTML that you see in the website search:

[image]

This will return you a JSON list of all the search results. An individual search result looks like this:

```
{
   "html":"<div style=\"float:left; width: 40px; height: 40px; background: url(https:\/\/www.devicespecifications.com\/images\/model\/50c75d98\/40\/main.jpg); no-repeat left top;\"><\/div><div class=\"icon-arrows\" style=\"float: left; margin: 12px 8px 0px 4px;\" onmousedown=\"App.comparison.add('50c75d98'); event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); return false;\"><\/div><div style=\"float: left; line-height: 40px;\">Nokia C210<\/div>",
   "url":"https:\/\/www.devicespecifications.com\/en\/model\/50c75d98",
   "type":1,
   "selectable":true
},
```

Parse the JSON and from that, you can find the url for the phone details page:

`"url":"https:\/\/www.devicespecifications.com\/en\/model\/50c75d98"`

(after unescaping it: `https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/50c75d98`)

Which gives you all the details (if you use JSOUP on the html):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You answer is very interesting. But I need the list of all phone models of all companies not only one company(Nokia). Also I replaced nokia with samsung, and I saw my phone model ( SM-A336E) is not in the list. Can you guide me further?

Comment: sorry, that's controlled by there website. It's a search function not a "list all" function :-). Please up vote or mark answered if you found useful though